# Is there anything preventing my code from running after inputting a number? (Lothar Collatz hypothesis)

Tags: python

```py
number = int(input("Enter any non-negative and non-zero integer number: "))
counter = 0

while number > 0 and number != 1:
    counter = +1

    if number % 2 == 0:
        number = number/2
        if number % 2 == 0:
            number = number/5
        else:
            number = (number*3)+1
    else:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            number = number/2
        else:
            number = (number*3)+1
print("Your number took", counter, "steps")
```

Comment: The `/` operator yields a floating point result.  Should you be using the integer division operator `//` instead?

Comment: Please note that your conditions are a bit weird. You check that `number % 2 == 0`, and yet in the `else` branch that is only triggered if `number` is odd, you again check to see if `number` is even.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to change the `counter= +1` to `counter += 1`, and you can change your if-else statement like this:

```
number = int(input("Enter any non-negative and non-zero integer number: "))
counter = 0

while number > 0 and number != 1:
    counter += 1
    print(number)

    if number % 2 == 0:
        number = number/2
    else:
        number = number*3+1

print("Your number took", counter, "steps")
```

Comment: You're doing floating point division (`/`) rather than integer division (`//`).

Answer (score -1):

```
c = int(input("Enter any non-negative and non-zero integer number:"))
step = 0

while c >1: 
        if c%2 == 0:
            c = c/2
        else:
         c = 3*c + 1
        step += 1
        print(int(c))

print("How many steps did it take?", step)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer also incorporates floating point division (`/`) rather than integer division (`//`) which will lead to bugs.

Answer (score -1):

```
C0 = int(input("Enter any integer:"))
i = 0
while C0 != 1:
    if C0 % 2 == 0:
        C0 = C0 // 2
        print(C0)
    elif C0 % 2 != 0:
        C0 = 3 * C0 + 1
        print(C0)
    i = i + 1
print("Step=", i)
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this answers the question. Also, whitespace is not evil.